# load external html files with handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I would like to create external Handlebars files using the following -

```
1. header- Contains html codes
2. footer- Contains html codes
3. nav- Contains html codes
4. search - Contains html codes
etc.
```

Is there a way with handlebars to do this, so that I can include each template if and when needed in a specific page. Not sure how to go about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! You can use [Handlebar partials](http://handlebarsjs.com/#partials) to do this. Simply register your header, nav, etc files as partials and then you can use this in your main template by doing something like this:

```
{{> header }}
{{> nav activePage=(activePage) }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using ASP.NET?
If you wanted to add content from other html files, I would highly recommend using
`@RenderPage()`If you use this, then you could set up a layout such as:

```
@RenderPage("header.html")
Some random description
@RenderPage("navigationbar.html")
@RenderPage("searchbar.html")
- Insert some content here -
@RenderPage("footer.html")
```

I'm certain that if you use this kind of layout, you'd get the appearance you would want. Obviously this is just an example, so you'd probably want to add some kind of CSS layout to suit your taste, but this is how I would go about it in ASP.NET.